# how to remove rows that appear same in two columns simultaneously in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe, DF1

```
   Id1   Id2  
0  286   409 
1  286   257  
2  409   286    
3  257   183
```

In this DF, for me rows `286,409` and `409,286` are same. I only want to keep one of these rows. All this I am doing is to build a network graph using `Networkx` python library.

I have tried achieving it by creating another df with interchanged columns like, DF2

```
   Id2   Id1
0  409   286
1  257   286
2  286   409
3  183   257
```

then I compare these two DFs using `isin` function something like this

`DF1[DF1[['Id1', 'Id2']].isin(DF2[['Id2', 'Id1']])]`
but it prints DF1 as it was.

**Expected output DF:**

```
   Id1   Id2  
0  286   409 
1  286   257     
3  257   183
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need sorting both columns by `np.sort` and filter by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with inverse mask:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(DF1[['Id1', 'Id2']].to_numpy(), axis=1), index=DF1.index)

df = DF1[~df1.duplicated()]
print (df)
   Id1  Id2
0  286  409
1  286  257
3  257  183
```

**Detail** : If use [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) with `axis=1` it sorting per rows, so first and third `'row'` are same:

```
print (np.sort(DF1[['Id1', 'Id2']].to_numpy(), axis=1))
[[286 409]
 [257 286]
 [286 409]
 [183 257]]
```

Then use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) function (working with DataFrame, so used DataFrame constructor):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(DF1[['Id1', 'Id2']].to_numpy(), axis=1), index=DF1.index)
print (df1)
     0    1
0  286  409
1  257  286
2  286  409
3  183  257
```

Third value is duplicate:

```
print (df1.duplicated())
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Last is necessary invert mask for remove duplicates, output is filtered in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (DF1[~df1.duplicated()])
   Id1  Id2
0  286  409
1  286  257
3  257  183
```

Comment: thank you, but `merge` merged both DFs and now I have 4 columns. How to proceed now?

Comment: @RishabhSahrawat - What is expected output?

Comment: thank you, this solution works, but I can't understand why `sorting` the column work, could you explain about it. :)

Comment: I understand. THank you very much for your help and time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can group your DataFrame by a sorted list of the column values

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """Id1   Id2
286   409
286   257
409   286
257   183"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep="\s+")

print(df.groupby(df.apply(lambda x: str(sorted(list(x))), axis=1)).first())
```

Result:

```
            Id1  Id2
[183, 257]  257  183
[257, 286]  286  257
[286, 409]  286  409
```

Comment: thank you very much :), your solution works but jezrael solution is more straight forward so will accept it as the answer.